# PHP methods outputting HTML with incorrect structure?

Tags: php, html, class, methods, structure

I have a strange situation that I've never encountered where the returned HTML from my class methods doesn't output in the correct structure. For some unknown reason, everything is nested inside the HTML within the first loop, second loop, etc.

**index.php**

```
<body>
some html...
<div class="usb-port-container">
<?= $generate->output('short_name',id,'hostname'); ?>
</div>
some html...
<div class="usb-port-container">
<?= $generate->output('short_name',id,'hostname'); ?>
</div>
some html...
</body>
```

**class.generate.php**

```
function __construct() {
    $this->getCopy = new getCopyData();
    $this->getDrive = new getDriveData();
    $this->helper = new helper();

}

function output ($short_name,$id,$hostname) {

    $portCount = $this->getCopy->portCount($hostname, 'total');

    for ($port = 0; $port < $portCount; ++$port) {
        if ($this->getCopy->probePort($hostname,$port)) {
            $default = $this->usbPortDefault($short_name,$id,$hostname,$port);

            return $default;
        } else {
            $details = $this->usbPortDetails($short_name,$id,$hostname,$port);

            return $details;
        }
    }
}

function usbPortDefault($short_name,$id,$hostname,$port) {

    $port_details =  '<div>
                        <div>----</div>
                        <div>----</div>
                    </div>';

    return $port_details;
}

function outputRecords($hostname,$port) {

    //get records data from database
    $records = $this->getCopy->records($hostname,$port);

    //create empty variable for HTML
    $records_html = "";

    foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $records_html .= '<div><span class="copy-group">' .$key. '</span><span class="copy-instance">' .$value. '</span></div>';
        } else {
            return '<div>Unable to get any group or instance</div>';
        }
    }

    return $records_html;
}

function usbPortDetails($short_name,$id,$hostname,$port) {

  $port_info = '';
  $port_info .= 'bunch of HTML';
  $port_info .= $this->outputRecords($hostname,$port);
  $port_info .= 'bunch of HTML';

  return $port_info;

}
```

My best guess as to the problem, is that there is an issue with the way I am returning the HTML or something with output buffering. I actually don't know if I need it within my class, but I've taken it out and issue is the same. I've also tried adding output buffering to index.html.

Here is a snippet of the source HTML. The first discrepancy I notice is that the `<div class="server-details"></div>` highlighted in blue doesn't belong there, it should be inside `<div class="dc-container"></div>` and adjacent to the prior `<div class="server-details"></div>`. After `port-data-left` should be `port-data-right` but it's nowhere to be found. I'm almost convinced at this point that there's a missing closing tag somewhere but I can't find it. It's been several years since I seriously did any development :D

[image]

**EDIT:** After further investigation, it appears that the final `$port_info` is not outputting and may be causing this problem. Is there an issue with `$port_info .= $this->outputRecords($hostname,$port);` being there?

Comment: also in function `output` cycle `for` always return on first loop no matter what

Comment: @Kazz `<?=` is already a `<?php echo` equivalent, so `<?= echo` will probably just display `1` which is the result of the `echo` function

Comment: ok, sorry i didn't know about this shorthand

Comment: Actually, that would work fine if there was only one `output` call and no other `$generate` objects used. The PHP doc states: "The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence." In this case, `ob_end_flush()` is only called once, that's why the nesting happens. You open one buffer with the contrstuctor, which is only called once, and output it in the last call, after all your intermediate HTML

Comment: I'll actually make this an answer because buffering is super useful but not well understood :-)

Comment: I've taken out the buffering just to remove that from the equation. Same issue occurs.

Comment: The other odd thing is that even HTML outside of functions is nested inside. Such as the following HTML on the entire page.

Comment: I'm just going to abandon trying to generate my content this way, there must be something fundamentally wrong with doing it. Will try to switch to an include/template method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you reuse you object instance using `$generate`, the constructor and destructor methods are only called once in this script.

The constructor starts a new output buffer using `ob_start()`, which means everything outputted by the `output` method will be buffered until you flush it.

The issue is, the flush only happens in the destructor, with `ob_end_flush()`, which is only executed once, after the last `output` call.

Because you `echo` the result of the method and start a buffer at the same time, the output must indeed be weird and some nesting / repetition occurs because the next output still adds to the buffer.

As pointed out in the comment, the easiest solution is to turn off the output buffering in the class.

You also need to clear `$port_info` at the beginning of the method to make this work, although it should be fine, unless `$port_info` is a global var?

This was probably not cleared in the initial Class in order to make it work when called several times, to concatenate the results (and buffer them, before outputting them all at once)

A good usage of buffers in the middle of a page is to redirect the output of a function to a variable.

For example, you could have a function that echoes code but you don't want it echoed.

You could then do something like:

```
Some HTML
<?php
ob_start();
call_to_some_function_that_normally_outputs_code();
$myvar = ob_get_clean();
?>
Rest of the HTML
```

Comment: When you speak about "clearing" `$port_info` are you referring to the buffering? I don't know what you mean there. Also, as I said this issue occurs without any buffering. It's as if the echoed HTML swallows the rest of the HTML on the entire page.

Comment: is `$port_info` a global var? If not, that's not your issue. What's the exact HTML output of this method? You're not outputting another `<html>` or `<body>` tag by any chance? Look at the source to make sure you don't have any catastrophically wrong markup.

Comment: I would also look at `bunch of HTML` and see if you don't have any open tag there. That would definitely "swallow" the code that is after.

Comment: I thought about the tags being an issue also, but if I copy all the html from that method and paste it above in `index.html` it displays as expected. `$port_info` is not global.

Comment: Please add the full output you see in the page source to the question.

Comment: I can't add the full HTML because it contains company specific information that I don't want to share. I will investigate a little more and add the relevant HTML.

Comment: Check the source and see what sits where. It will give you an indication as where the issue is. If the order of elements is correct, then you just have a markup issue because your browser can't parse it properly.

Comment: @EternalHour hes right about `$port_info` because in function `usbPortDetails` you do `$port_info .= 'bunch of HTML';` which is wrong and should cause error because `$port_info` is undefined and you try to do concatenate to undefined variable - so turn on error reporting while you dev

Comment: True but that would just trigger a notice error, nothing catastrophic and definitely not responsible for the issue the OP sees here. To me that's just a markup issue.

Comment: right but also turning error reporting on could show another error which cause this problem

Comment: @Kazz I accidentally left out the originally defined empty variable of the code and have corrected that in the question. It does exist in the actual markup. Sorry.